# Error n reading csv file: utf-8 codec cant decode

Tags: python, csv, merge

While running the code to merge(basically inner join) two csv files I am facing an error while reading csv file. My code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
s1= pd.read_csv(".../noun.csv")
s2= pd.read_csv(".../verb.csv")
merged= s1.merge(s2, on=("userID" ,"sentID"), how ="inner")
merged.to_excel(".../merge1.xlsx",index = False)
```

Error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 5: invalid start byte
```

example of my content is:

```
verb file

userID  sentID  verb
['3477'  1     ['am', 'were', 'having', 'attended', 'stopped']
['3477'  2     ['felt', 'thrusting']

noun file
userID  sentID  Sentences
['3477'   1    Thursday,
['3477'   1    November
```

Comment: So your files are not UTF-8 encoded. Pick a different encoding, one that actually matches your file contents.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the relevant part of your input.

Comment: How do I know that which is proper? Do you have any idea?

Comment: No, I don't know what's in your files. If you don't know either, you need to go and ask whomever provided the files.

Comment: I have add type of my file. @ Martjin

Comment: You have a character with code `\x92`. In Windows 1252 it could be the left tick *’* (ex. in french *l’orange*). In code page 850, it could be *Æ*. If you show the part of your input files that contains non ascii characters, we could possibly help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library that attempts to detect the encoding, for example [cchardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cchardet/1.0.0):

```
pip install cchardet
```

If you use python 2.X you also need a [backport](https://github.com/ryanhiebert/backports.csv) of the CSV library. They support Unicode natively, while Python 2's csv does not:

```
pip install backports.csv
```

Then in your code you can do something like this:

```
import cchardet
import io
from backports import csv

# detect encoding
with io.open(filename, mode="rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
detect = cchardet.detect(data)
encoding_ = detect['encoding']
# retrieve data
with io.open(filename, encoding=encoding_) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, ...)
...
```

I don't know pandas, but you can do something like this:

```
# retrieve data
s1= pd.read_csv(".../noun.csv", encoding=encoding_)
```